# Prototype: 12 DC car battery to power standard 120 VAC hand tools

Tags: powertools, battery, inverter

**Objective**:  Today I power my tools (drill, circular-saw, reciprocal saw etc.) in my shed by running a power line from my house.  I wish to install solar power panels on my shed; however, before I do so, I wish to make sure everything is theoretically and practically correct.

**Prototype**: My thoughts and calculation:

1. A circular saw needs the most power compared to other tools (~13 amps); hence I used it for my baseline worst-case scenario. i.e. the circular saw needs 13 amps * 120 volts = 1,560 watts
2. With a 12v DC battery, 1560 watts would imply that I would need 130 amps
3. A normal car battery at full charge stores about 48 amp-hours
4. This implies that a fully charged car battery would run my circular-saw for about 48 amp-hours / 130 amps = 0.36 hours = 0.36 * 60 ~ 22 minutes
5. I plan on converting the 12v DC to 120-volt AC using a standard OTS inverter (~$20)

**Questions**:

1. Is my (sizing) calculation correct?
2. Is my prototype’s design reasonable?
3. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a car (SLI) battery for deep-cycle service?

Comment: 1) You’re not going to get a real 1500W inverter for $20. 2) Motors generally take a *lot* more than their rated power to start (like 3X). Circuit breakers and wires are fine with momentary overloads, inverters are generally less tolerant. 3) Never discharge a lead acid battery 100%.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel: No particular reason why I chose a car battery; I just needed an electric store and thought that a car-battery would do it.  Would appreciate your thoughts and recommendations for improvement.

Comment: @nobody I think by "OTS", OP means the eBay/Amazon Marketplace/AliExpress/Banggood Chinese junkstream. After all when stuff is on Amazon why would a consumer think it's bad?

Comment: Nobody: Agree with your point about 3X power needed.  Guess I'll have to think about 3,000+ inverter (AIMS) to make this happen; May also need multiple 12 v DC batteries to meet spike requirements (5K surge) and long usage-runs (2.5KW ); I mentioned $20 inverter as a prototype (since I have it).  Agree 100% that I would need something better like what they have in a back-up sump-pump.  Thanks for your input!!!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I did check Amazon before posting - the absolute cheapest and sketchiest-looking “1500W” (yeah right) inverter there is $60.

Comment: Nobody: I checked Grainger's catalog and found a reasonably priced inverter (not mentioning name on purpose as it frowned upon) with following specs -  60 Hz, 3KW peak/1.5K nominal, modified sine-wave, 10 to 15V DC  i/p, 110 to 125V AC o/p.  Is this good enough for shed/circular-saw use case (and possibly sump-pump in the event of a power outage).  Questions: 1) Is there a need or big tangible benefit to pure-sine wave 2) Is 3KW peak adequate (2x nominal) or should I consider 4.5KW as you mentioned. I seek your opinion as the cost shoots up quite a bit (to $800 from ~$300).

Comment: Contrarian view: just buy cordless tools. A basic charger for the batteries will draw about 2A, which massively reduces your inverter/storage requirements.

Comment: The real objective of my prototype is to size solar-panel requirement, conversion and storage design.  I used power circular saw to  size upper-limit for peak-power. My current investment is mostly in corded tools and my home-improvement project are mostly a hobby.   So, I 'd rather put money into a good inverter, solar-kit and deep-cycle 12v battery rather than invest in a new set of tools with each costing a couple of hundred dollars.  Additionally, a battery unit would be half (?) as powerful and after you consider peak-draw with start/stop, I may have to charge the tool's battery often.

Answer (score 1):

I think your math all checks out and you have good command of the concepts here.

You need a few more concepts though.

Lead-acid batteries are bizarre. While they are cheap, they do not work the way they obviously ought to work.  The #1 thing they don't do is deep-discharge well.  If you run a lead-acid battery from 90% to 10%, you will get three to 100 of these full cycles before the battery loses capacity dramatically and is kaput.

People who depend on lead-acid batteries for deep-cycling find they can only use the top 30% of capacity on a regular basis or they will get very short life out of their battery.

Further, the type of battery matters a great deal. Car starting batteries are made for delivering a big one-shot impulse, but do *particularly badly* in deep-cycling.  Deep-cycle batteries do well with deep cycling, but have too much internal resistance to start an engine in adverse conditions.

They are a big pain in the butt, but you like the price.

If you want a battery that actually behaves like it says on the tin, then look at lithium (which has different kinds of feisty) - or the perfect large battery is nickel-cadmium or nickel-iron.  I have a set of NiCds that came to us *as scrap* in 1986, and they're still going.  Nickel-iron is impervious to almost any operational abuse, and last 40 years, but have quite high internal resistance so are not good at starting engines.

Comment: Harper: Thank you SO very much for your educational and insightful comments;  When you say "deep-cycle" battery, I suppose you mean the type of battery used in backup (battery) sump-pump.  I will do some research/investigation into  "deep-cycle" battery....I have heard about them but don't know the details. As for NiCd, NiFe batteries, what should looking for on  (any) eMarketPlace.  I am asking as the ones that I (just) saw on Amazon had low amp-hours (max=3 Amp-hours).  Guess I need a lot more storage capacity.

Comment: @user97485 -- there is no good reason to be shopping for this sort of stuff online, *especially* not on Amazon Marketplace...if you want deep-cycle lead-acid, head to a place like Interstate Battery or Batteries+Bulbs, I reckon.  (If you really want to shop for it online, I'd try a MRO supplier like McMaster-Carr, MSC, Grainger/Zoro, or such)

Comment: Thank you, Sir!! Will follow your advice and check at Grainger, B+B since they are in my area.

Comment: Harper:  I checked B&B's catalog and I found a 33AH, Deep-Cycle, 12v battery  that seemed to fit my need.  However, they were all lead-acid type and NOT Lithium/NiCd/NiMH as you mentioned. Thoughts?

Comment: You're gonna need some more concepts in the area of battery procurement :)   Lead-acid deep-cycle batteries are best bought the same place you buy car batteries, or alternately, 2 golf-cart batteries. For instance [CostCo](https://www.costco.com/CatalogSearch?dept=All&keyword=Interstate+Recreational+Batteries) has some deals (to convert from Reserve Minutes to AH, multiply by 0.416).  Optimize for AH per dollar. Remember you can only count on using about 30% of published AH.  Never mail-order lead-acid; they're too heavy!

Comment: For NiCd/NiMH, you need to talk to solar/home-power people - get on their forums and find their secrets for acquisition. Another option is to talk to an aviation FBO, and see if they'll sell you used NiCd wet cells from aircraft.  For lithium, again talk to the home-power people, but you may have to either pay a lot ($110 for 33AH is about right) or build 'em yourself out of 18650s.  Remember the protection circuit, unless you like fires. @user97485

Comment: Harper: Thank you SO very much for your educational, insightful and constructive recommendation.  I was planning on purchasing the 12v deep cycle battery @Menards (that is close to my home) but CostCo deal seems better.  And as for NiCd/NiMH, I will hold on that for now as I am still in prototype phase.  And while building a Lithium 18650-pack seems ideal, I will need a lot of these cells getting me to baseline battery cost of $500+ ($13 / battery * 4 * 33 / 2.6).

Comment: @user97485 Yes, *feel free* to use two 6V golf-cart batteries.  The amp-hours will be whatever the battery spec says (i.e. two 6V batteries @ 250AH will be 250AH @ 12V).